# Jenkins running as service ignoring system properties

Tags: java, jenkins

We had a situation where our Jenkins server had to be rebuild completely. We used the latest version and it is running. We however have a problem with https connections either being on the plugin search or calls to us login.

It gives us the following error

```
un 03 12:15:51 cca-t2-jenkins-master systemd[1]: Started Jenkins Continuous Integration Server.
Jun 03 12:15:51 cca-t2-jenkins-master sudo[18486]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Jun 03 12:15:57 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[18512]: 2022-06-03 16:15:57.036+0000 [id=749]        INFO        h.p.sonar.SonarBuildWrapper#setUp: Injecting SonarQube environment variables using the configuration: SonarCloud
Jun 03 12:15:57 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[18512]: 2022-06-03 16:15:57.065+0000 [id=749]        INFO        h.p.sonar.SonarBuildWrapper#createLoggerDecorator: Masking SonarQube passwords
Jun 03 12:16:04 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[18512]: 2022-06-03 16:16:04.393+0000 [id=15]        WARNING        o.j.p.workflow.job.WorkflowRun#checkouts: JENKINS-26761: no checkouts in hassan-test #36
Jun 03 12:16:04 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[18512]: 2022-06-03 16:16:04.396+0000 [id=15]        WARNING        o.j.p.workflow.job.WorkflowRun#checkouts: JENKINS-26761: no checkouts in hassan-test #32
Jun 03 12:16:08 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[18512]: 2022-06-03 16:16:08.828+0000 [id=16]        WARNING        h.i.i.InstallUncaughtExceptionHandler#handleException: Caught unhandled exception with ID 81b59c52-496a-4052-9073-427dacbaab2c
Jun 03 12:16:08 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[18512]: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
Jun 03 12:16:08 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[18512]:         at java.base/java.security.cert.PKIXParameters.setTrustAnchors(PKIXParameters.java:200)
Jun 03 12:16:08 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[18512]:         at java.base/java.security.cert.PKIXParameters.<init>(PKIXParameters.java:120)
Jun 03 12:16:08 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[18512]:         at java.base/java.security.cert.PKIXBuilderParameters.<init>(PKIXBuilderParameters.java:104)
Jun 03 12:16:08 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[18512]:         at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.<init>(PKIXValidator.java:99)
Jun 03 12:16:08 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[18512]: Caused: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error
Jun 03 12:16:08 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[18512]:         at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.<init>(PKIXValidator.java:102)
Jun 03 12:16:08 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[18512]:         at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.getInstance(Validator.java:181)
Jun 03 12:16:08 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[18512]:         at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.getValidator(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:300)
Jun 03 12:16:08 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[18512]:         at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedInit(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:176)
Jun 03 12:16:08 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[18512]:         at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:189)
Jun 03 12:16:08 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[18512]:         at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:129)
Jun 03 12:16:08 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[18512]:         at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1341)
Jun 03 12:16:08 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[18512]:         at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.onConsumeCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:1232)
Jun 03 12:16:08 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[18512]:         at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:1175)
Jun 03 12:16:08 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[18512]:         at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392)
Jun 03 12:16:08 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[18512]:         at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:443)
Jun 03 12:16:08 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[18512]:         at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:421)
Jun 03 12:16:08 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[18512]:         at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:182)
Jun 03 12:16:08 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[18512]:         at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172)
Jun 03 12:16:08 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[18512]:         at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1501)
Jun 03 12:16:08 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[18512]:         at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1411)
Jun 03 12:16:08 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[18512]:         at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:451)
Jun 03 12:16:08 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[18512]: Caused: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
Jun 03 12:16:08 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[18512]:         at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:133)
Jun 03 12:16:08 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[18512]:         at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:352)
Jun 03 12:16:08 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[18512]:         at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:295)
Jun 03 12:16:08 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[18512]:         at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:290)
Jun 03 12:16:08 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[18512]:         at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1684)
Jun 03 12:16:08 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[18512]:         at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:466)
Jun 03 12:16:08 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[18512]:         at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:422)
Jun 03 12:16:08 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[18512]:         at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:572)
Jun 03 12:16:08 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[18512]:         at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:197)
Jun 03 12:16:08 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[18512]:         at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1367)
Jun 03 12:16:08 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[18512]:         at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1342)
Jun 03 12:16:08 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[18512]:         at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:246)
Jun 03 12:16:08 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[18512]:         at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:77)
Jun 03 12:16:08 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[18512]:         at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:972)
Jun 03 12:16:08 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[18512]:         at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:283)
Jun 03 12:16:08 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[18512]:         at com.google.api.client.auth.openidconnect.IdTokenResponse.execute(IdTokenResponse.java:120)
Jun 03 12:16:08 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[18512]:         at org.jenkinsci.plugins.googlelogin.GoogleOAuth2SecurityRealm$2.onSuccess(GoogleOAuth2SecurityRealm.java:208)
Jun 03 12:16:08 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[18512]:         at org.jenkinsci.plugins.googlelogin.OAuthSession.doFinishLogin(OAuthSession.java:107)
Jun 03 12:16:08 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[18512]:         at org.jenkinsci.plugins.googlelogin.GoogleOAuth2SecurityRealm.doFinishLogin(GoogleOAuth2SecurityRealm.java:299)
Jun 03 12:16:08 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[18512]:         at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(MethodHandle.java:710)
Jun 03 12:16:08 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[18512]:         at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$MethodFunction.invoke(Function.java:397)
Jun 03 12:16:08 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[18512]:         at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:409)
Jun 03 12:16:08 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[18512]:         at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:207)
Jun 03 12:16:08 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[18512]:         at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:140)
```

I managed to have it running by running manually the following command:

```
/usr/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=pkcs12 -jar /usr/share/java/jenkins.war --webroot=%C/jenkins/war --httpPort=8080
```

So i tried to add the values in `/etc/default/jenkins` which seems to be ignored completely. I updated the service with `systemctl edit jenkins` with the following:

```
[Service]
Environment="JENKINS_HOME=/data/jenkins"
Environment="JAVA_OPTS=\"-XshowSettings:properties -Djavax.net.debug=all -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=pkcs12\" "
```

Only the first JVM argument is taken

```
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]: VM settings:
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:     Max. Heap Size (Estimated): 1.95G
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:     Using VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]: Property settings:
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:     awt.toolkit = sun.awt.X11.XToolkit
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:     file.encoding = UTF-8
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:     file.separator = /
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:     java.awt.graphicsenv = sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:     java.awt.printerjob = sun.print.PSPrinterJob
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:     java.class.path = /usr/share/java/jenkins.war
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:     java.class.version = 55.0
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:     java.home = /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:     java.io.tmpdir = /tmp
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:     java.library.path = /usr/java/packages/lib
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:         /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:         /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:         /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:         /usr/lib/jni
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:         /lib
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:         /usr/lib
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:     java.runtime.name = OpenJDK Runtime Environment
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:     java.runtime.version = 11.0.14+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.16.04
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:     java.specification.name = Java Platform API Specification
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:     java.specification.vendor = Oracle Corporation
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:     java.specification.version = 11
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:     java.vendor = Ubuntu
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:     java.vendor.url = https://ubuntu.com/
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:     java.vendor.url.bug = https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-lts
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:     java.version = 11.0.14
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:     java.version.date = 2022-01-18
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:     java.vm.compressedOopsMode = 32-bit
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:     java.vm.info = mixed mode, sharing
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:     java.vm.name = OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:     java.vm.specification.name = Java Virtual Machine Specification
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:     java.vm.specification.vendor = Oracle Corporation
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:     java.vm.specification.version = 11
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:     java.vm.vendor = Ubuntu
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:     java.vm.version = 11.0.14+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.16.04
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:     jdk.debug = release
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:     line.separator = \n
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:     os.arch = amd64
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:     os.name = Linux
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:     os.version = 4.4.0-210-generic
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:     path.separator = :
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:     sun.arch.data.model = 64
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:     sun.boot.library.path = /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:     sun.cpu.endian = little
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:     sun.cpu.isalist =
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:     sun.io.unicode.encoding = UnicodeLittle
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:     sun.java.command = /usr/share/java/jenkins.war --webroot=%C/jenkins/war --httpPort=8080
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:     sun.java.launcher = SUN_STANDARD
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:     sun.jnu.encoding = UTF-8
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:     sun.management.compiler = HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:     sun.os.patch.level = unknown
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:     user.country = US
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:     user.dir = /var/lib/jenkins
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:     user.home = /var/lib/jenkins
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:     user.language = en
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:     user.name = jenkins
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:     user.timezone =
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]: Locale settings:
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:     default locale = English (United States)
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:     default display locale = English (United States)
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:     default format locale = English (United States)
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:     available locales = , af, af_NA, af_ZA, agq, agq_CM, ak, ak_GH,
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]: Operating System Metrics:
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:     Provider: cgroupv1
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:     Effective CPU Count: 4
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:     CPU Period: 100000us
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:     CPU Quota: -1
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:     CPU Shares: -1
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:     List of Processors, 4 total:
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:     0 1 2 3
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:     List of Effective Processors, 4 total:
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:     0 1 2 3
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:     List of Memory Nodes, 1 total:
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:     0
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:     List of Available Memory Nodes, 1 total:
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:     0
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:     CPUSet Memory Pressure Enabled: false
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:     Memory Limit: Unlimited
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:     Memory Soft Limit: Unlimited
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:     Memory & Swap Limit: Unlimited
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:     Kernel Memory Limit: Unlimited
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:     TCP Memory Limit: Unlimited
Jun 03 12:24:32 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:     Out Of Memory Killer Enabled: true
Jun 03 12:24:33 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]: Running from: /usr/share/java/jenkins.war
Jun 03 12:24:33 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]: 2022-06-03 16:24:33.297+0000 [id=1]        INFO        org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log#initialized: Logging initialized @479ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog
Jun 03 12:24:33 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]: 2022-06-03 16:24:33.360+0000 [id=1]        INFO        winstone.Logger#logInternal: Beginning extraction from war file
Jun 03 12:24:33 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]: 2022-06-03 16:24:33.385+0000 [id=1]        WARNING        o.e.j.s.handler.ContextHandler#setContextPath: Empty contextPath
Jun 03 12:24:33 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]: 2022-06-03 16:24:33.445+0000 [id=1]        INFO        org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server#doStart: jetty-9.4.46.v20220331; built: 2022-03-31T16:38:08.030Z; git: bc17a0369a11ecf40bb92c839b9ef0a8ac50ea18; jvm 11.0.14+9-Ub
Jun 03 12:24:33 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]: 2022-06-03 16:24:33.728+0000 [id=1]        INFO        o.e.j.w.StandardDescriptorProcessor#visitServlet: NO JSP Support for /, did not find org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet
Jun 03 12:24:33 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]: 2022-06-03 16:24:33.767+0000 [id=1]        INFO        o.e.j.s.s.DefaultSessionIdManager#doStart: DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0
Jun 03 12:24:33 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]: 2022-06-03 16:24:33.767+0000 [id=1]        INFO        o.e.j.s.s.DefaultSessionIdManager#doStart: No SessionScavenger set, using defaults
Jun 03 12:24:33 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]: 2022-06-03 16:24:33.768+0000 [id=1]        INFO        o.e.j.server.session.HouseKeeper#startScavenging: node0 Scavenging every 660000ms
Jun 03 12:24:34 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]: 2022-06-03 16:24:34.162+0000 [id=1]        INFO        hudson.WebAppMain#contextInitialized: Jenkins home directory: /data/jenkins found at: EnvVars.masterEnvVars.get("JENKINS_HOME")
Jun 03 12:24:34 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]: 2022-06-03 16:24:34.350+0000 [id=1]        INFO        o.e.j.s.handler.ContextHandler#doStart: Started w.@5b6813df{Jenkins v2.350,/,file:///var/lib/jenkins/%25C/jenkins/war/,AVAILABLE}{/var/lib/jenkins/%C/jenkins/war
Jun 03 12:24:34 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]: 2022-06-03 16:24:34.379+0000 [id=1]        INFO        o.e.j.server.AbstractConnector#doStart: Started ServerConnector@4bb4de6a{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:8080}
Jun 03 12:24:34 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]: 2022-06-03 16:24:34.379+0000 [id=1]        INFO        org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server#doStart: Started @1562ms
Jun 03 12:24:34 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]: 2022-06-03 16:24:34.380+0000 [id=24]        INFO        winstone.Logger#logInternal: Winstone Servlet Engine running: controlPort=disabled
Jun 03 12:24:34 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]: 2022-06-03 16:24:34.713+0000 [id=30]        INFO        jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Started initialization
Jun 03 12:24:34 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]: 2022-06-03 16:24:34.855+0000 [id=30]        INFO        jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Listed all plugins
Jun 03 12:24:38 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]: 2022-06-03 16:24:38.769+0000 [id=37]        INFO        jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Prepared all plugins
Jun 03 12:24:38 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]: 2022-06-03 16:24:38.796+0000 [id=36]        INFO        jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Started all plugins
Jun 03 12:24:38 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]: 2022-06-03 16:24:38.817+0000 [id=31]        INFO        jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Augmented all extensions
Jun 03 12:24:38 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]: WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
Jun 03 12:24:38 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]: WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7$1 (file:/var/lib/jenkins/%25C/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/groovy-all-2.4.21.jar) to constructor java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup(java.lang.
Jun 03 12:24:38 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]: WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7$1
Jun 03 12:24:38 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]: WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
Jun 03 12:24:38 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]: WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Jun 03 12:24:40 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]: 2022-06-03 16:24:40.021+0000 [id=32]        INFO        h.p.b.g.GlobalTimeOutConfiguration#load: global timeout not set
Jun 03 12:24:40 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]: 2022-06-03 16:24:40.378+0000 [id=33]        INFO        hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer#tryReconnect: Attempting to reconnect slave1
Jun 03 12:24:40 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]: 2022-06-03 16:24:40.380+0000 [id=33]        INFO        hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer#tryReconnect: Attempting to reconnect slave2
Jun 03 12:24:40 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]: 2022-06-03 16:24:40.383+0000 [id=33]        INFO        hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer#tryReconnect: Attempting to reconnect slave3
Jun 03 12:24:40 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]: 2022-06-03 16:24:40.384+0000 [id=33]        INFO        hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer#tryReconnect: Attempting to reconnect slave4
Jun 03 12:24:40 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]: 2022-06-03 16:24:40.409+0000 [id=33]        INFO        jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: System config loaded
Jun 03 12:24:40 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]: 2022-06-03 16:24:40.866+0000 [id=32]        INFO        jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: System config adapted
Jun 03 12:24:40 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]: 2022-06-03 16:24:40.955+0000 [id=35]        INFO        jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Loaded all jobs
Jun 03 12:24:40 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]: 2022-06-03 16:24:40.958+0000 [id=30]        INFO        jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Configuration for all jobs updated
Jun 03 12:24:41 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]: 2022-06-03 16:24:41.004+0000 [id=74]        INFO        hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork#lambda$doRun$1: Started Download metadata
Jun 03 12:24:41 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]: 2022-06-03 16:24:41.195+0000 [id=35]        INFO        jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Completed initialization
Jun 03 12:24:41 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]: 2022-06-03 16:24:41.345+0000 [id=23]        INFO        hudson.lifecycle.Lifecycle#onReady: Jenkins is fully up and running
Jun 03 12:24:41 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]: 2022-06-03 16:24:41.467+0000 [id=74]        WARNING        h.m.DownloadService$Downloadable#updateNow: No tool installer metadata found for jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.MirrorNodeJSInstaller
Jun 03 12:24:41 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]: 2022-06-03 16:24:41.469+0000 [id=74]        INFO        hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork#lambda$doRun$1: Finished Download metadata. 440 ms
Jun 03 12:24:43 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]: [06/03/22 12:24:43] SSH Launch of slave4 on 10.178.52.3 completed in 2,902 ms
Jun 03 12:24:43 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]: [06/03/22 12:24:43] SSH Launch of slave1 on 10.178.52.112 completed in 2,942 ms
Jun 03 12:24:43 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]: [06/03/22 12:24:43] SSH Launch of slave2 on 10.178.52.125 completed in 3,018 ms
Jun 03 12:24:43 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]: [06/03/22 12:24:43] SSH Launch of slave3 on 10.178.52.42 completed in 3,353 ms
Jun 03 12:25:13 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]: 2022-06-03 16:25:13.429+0000 [id=13]        WARNING        h.i.i.InstallUncaughtExceptionHandler#handleException: Caught unhandled exception with ID 220cd647-d02c-46cf-98d9-cd79c069cda3
Jun 03 12:25:13 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
Jun 03 12:25:13 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:         at java.base/java.security.cert.PKIXParameters.setTrustAnchors(PKIXParameters.java:200)
Jun 03 12:25:13 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:         at java.base/java.security.cert.PKIXParameters.<init>(PKIXParameters.java:120)
Jun 03 12:25:13 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:         at java.base/java.security.cert.PKIXBuilderParameters.<init>(PKIXBuilderParameters.java:104)
Jun 03 12:25:13 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:         at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.<init>(PKIXValidator.java:99)
Jun 03 12:25:13 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]: Caused: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error
Jun 03 12:25:13 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:         at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.<init>(PKIXValidator.java:102)
Jun 03 12:25:13 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:         at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.getInstance(Validator.java:181)
Jun 03 12:25:13 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:         at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.getValidator(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:300)
Jun 03 12:25:13 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:         at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedInit(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:176)
Jun 03 12:25:13 cca-t2-jenkins-master jenkins[31198]:         at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:189)
```

The ps seems to have all the required parameters:

```
jenkins  31198     1 21 12:24 ?        00:00:54 /usr/bin/java -XshowSettings:properties -Djavax.net.debug=all -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=pkcs12 -jar /usr/share/java/je
nkins.war --webroot=%C/jenkins/war --httpPort=8080
```

Anyone could help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out what was the problem.

It was the service environment variable which was wrong. It should have been

```
Environment="JAVA_OPTS=-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=pkcs12"
```

instead of

```
Environment="JAVA_OPTS=\"-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=pkcs12\""
```

Comment: Hi. I'm getting the same error when using the AWS CodeBuid plugin from a container which image is jenkins:lts-alpine. I don't know how to solve it, do you have any idea?

Comment: @sgrumo what is the error you are getting? only the first parameter used? If so, can you post some of you config so i can try to help you?